# How to wrap text around div

Tags: css

I am battling with the css to wrap text inside div. I have applied white-spacing, word break but nothing happened.

Link http://fiduciaryconsulting.org/index.php/services/90-services/200-demo

[Screenshot of section with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIMPr.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You need to put a [mcve] in your question when asking for code assistance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: As others have already correctly suggested, you need to remove the `white-space` rule declared for the element in question - this is the right solution. You should mark one of those answers as correct and find an alternative to keep those blocks aligned in the way you need them - if you're unsuccessful you're always welcome to post a new question addressing that issue; which would be separate from this one.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `white-space: nowrap` from the selector `.boxes li a` and it will work

Comment: Thanks Clyde, I have removed the white-space property and the text wrapped well but some boxes are now longer than the other.[http://fiduciaryconsulting.org/index.php/services/90-services/200-demo]

Answer (score 2):

Remove `white-space: nowrap;` from the link tag.

Check out these articles for more info about wrapping long words and URLs:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/
- https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/
- https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/

Comment: Thanks Ted, I have removed the white-space property and the text wrapped well but some boxes are now longer than the other.

Comment: Making the box heights equal is a whole separate issue ;) If it was a single row you could use `display: table-cell;`, but for multiple columns you will either have to use JS or `display: flex;`.

Here are some flexbox links to check out:
1) http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/
2) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
3) http://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv/
4) http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html#wraprow

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: nowrap;` would be the culprit for this one. remove it from the following CSS, or you can comment it out like below:

```
.boxes li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 60px 10px 60px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #3366ff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 30px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

*You can find this selector's CSS rules on lines 29-44 on the file: http://fiduciaryconsulting.org/templates/jsn_pixel_free/css/template.css*

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I downvoted Nikki's incomplete/incorrect answer. You have a positive score on your answer. You can also check my history; no downvotes were given to you. *at any rate, why does it matter? We're trying to help the OP*

Comment: Sorry. It was not meant for you. I saw a downvote on your answer and asked why was it downvoted. It helps to know why a answer was downvoted.

Comment: I guess because you do not have that privilege yet.